# Multiple Spring Boot datasources as Regular and JNDI based on Env

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

In my SpringBoot application I need to support two datasources. Is it possible to have my DatabaseConfig class support a regular datasource in my local environment but have it work as a JNDI datasource in my other environments?  The other datasource will always be a regular datasource in all env's.

```
@Configuration 
public class DatabaseConfig { 

    @Primary 
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.firstDatasource") 
    @Bean(name = "firstDatasource") 
    public DataSource contentDatasource() { 
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build(); 
    } 

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource") 
    @Bean(name = "secondDatasource") 
    public DataSource secondDatasource() { 
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build(); 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "jdbcFirst") 
    public JdbcTemplate firstJdbcTemplate(DataSource firstDatasource)   { 
            return new JdbcTemplate(firstDatasource()); 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "jdbcSecond") 
    public JdbcTemplate secondJdbcTemplate(DataSource secondDatasource) { 
            return new JdbcTemplate(secondDatasource()); 
    } 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, take a look at `@Profile` annotation. You can use it in conjunction with `@Bean`, `@Component` (also for children annotations like `@Service`,...) or `@Configuration`.

Take a look at [this Spring docs section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-java) to investigate how it can be used.

Take a look at [this Spring Boot docs section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles) to investigate how to define profiles for Spring Boot application. Define profile via command line is considered as best option.